# Let $x$ is the angle of the diagonal lines of a unit cube, then what are the possible values of $\cos x$?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, inner-products, geometric-construction

1. Let $x$ is the angle of the diagonal lines of a unit cube(the cube with edges $1$), then what are the possible values of $\cos x$?

My attempt: Since the dot products of the diagonal lines are $1$ or $-1$,and the lengths of them are all $3^{1/2}$, so $\cos x$ are
$$1/(3^{1/2}3^{1/2})=\cos x=1/3$$ or $$-1/(3^{1/2}3^{1/2})=\cos x=-1/3.$$

Am I right? If I am wrong, then please correct my answers.

2. Moreover, it should have $16$ possible $\cos x$ values, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, you can have a clearer view by using coordinates, with vertices $(\pm 1, \pm 1, \pm 1)$, the cube's center $O$ being the origin of coordinates (see figure below).

**Remark:** instead of a cube with unit sides, we have a cube with sidelength $2$. We compensate it by taking the half-diagonals, finally giving the same results.

If we considering the different cases:

$$\vec{OA}\begin{pmatrix}\ \ 1\\ \ \ 1\\-1\end{pmatrix}, \vec{OB}\begin{pmatrix}-1\\ \ \ 1\\-1\end{pmatrix},\cdots \vec{OF}\begin{pmatrix}-1\\ \ \ 1\\ \ \ 1\end{pmatrix},\cdots$$

we find that, using formula $\vec{u}.\vec{v}=\frac{u_x*v_x+u_y*v_y+u_z*v_z}{\|\vec{u}\|*|\vec{v}\|}$:

$$\vec{OA}.\vec{OB}=\frac{1*(-1)+1*1+(-1)*(-1)}{\sqrt{3}\sqrt{3}}=\frac13$$

whereas:

$$\vec{OA}.\vec{OF}=\frac{1*(-1)+1*1+(-1)*1}{\sqrt{3}\sqrt{3}}=-\frac13$$

and we have only this kind of dot-product as you have found (one must of course eliminate the cases where the dot product is $-1$, because it corresponds to opposite half-diagonals), giving finally two kinds of angles only, that can be either

$$\cos^{-1}\tfrac13\approx 70.53°, \ \ \text{or} \ \ \cos^{-1}(-\tfrac13)\approx 109.47°  $$

This last angle, $109.47°$ is well know by chemists : it is the "bond angle" in $CH_4$, the methane tetrahedric molecule.

I have materialized (black lines) the way a regular tetrahedron $BDEG$ is inscribed in a cube.

(the following Geogebra figure can be "animated" : click [here](https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/kw3meehp) for that).

[image]

Comment: Strange to be downvoted for a correct answer to a well written and detailed question...

Comment: Could I know what software do you use to draw that cube in the middle?

Comment: Moreover, I appreciate you for answering my question very much.

Comment: Thanks. The software I use is **Geogebra**. I advise you to click on the indicated link and wait 5 seconds for the image to appear, then drag the mouse pointer on the figure in order to change the view point . The same kind of figure could be achieved with **Desmos**.